Syncing state between two or more browser tabs
Logic in my app is that I update something in settings page and after it is successfully updated I mutate user data which is used in further requests (like creating order with users chosen currency etc.). But if I update in one browser tab I am still able to go to another tab(which was opened before mutating user) and try to create order request is sent using redundant code (field in user entity). Is there a native way to sync tabs ?

To share data between two tabs, you must use local storage, cookies, etc.
You can use the storage event to detect changes in local storage values in other tabs.
window.addEventListener("storage", function () {

}, false);


Note that the storage event will not fire on the tab that caused the change to localstorage.

yeah i thought about that, but trying to come up with something more eloquent

more eloquent??? good luck

@howardwolowitz Do you have any concerns? Take the easy way.

BroadcastChannel is more eloquent i would say

I agree that BroadcastChannel is a cooler solution. However, it doesn't work in older versions of Safari (before 2022-03-14). (Maybe you are worried about this)
